# I implement multiple npm command on the Linux System,all of them is start a Website use nodejs,let them run on the background

Tags: node.js

`"start-client": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./server/index.js",
"start-api": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node ./server/api/index.js",
"start-pro": "concurrently \"npm run start-client\"  \"npm run start-api\""`

The `npm run start-pro` is run on the Liunx System is success,but i close the session then the server is over.

Is Also ok when i run `npm run start-pro &` command,is appear 503 error when i colse session.

当我执行nohup npm run start-pro &这个命令的时候，在项目的根目录出现了nohup.output的文件，里面记录了错误:

Appear the error when i `nohup npm run start-pro &` command,the error is in the `nohup.out` file:

> p2@0.1.0 start-pro /website/pgyer
>   concurrently "npm run start-client"  "npm run start-api"
>
> events.js:160
>        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>        ^
>
> Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, read
>      at Error (native)
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! p2@0.1.0 start-pro: `concurrently "npm run start-client"  "npm run 
>   start-api"`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR! 
>   npm ERR! Failed at the p2@0.1.0 start-pro script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
>   logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-07-18T00_30_14_968Z-debug.log

Try again!Now implement `nohup npm run start-api &` first is success!Then,implement `nobup npm run start-client &` command is success too!

> So,i want to kown,how can i do one command to start two server:`start-client`and `start-api`,and i close the session the server is ok?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)". Also please take the tour and read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please help the helpers to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use concurrently install it using

**npm install -g concurrently**

or if you are using it from npm scripts:

**npm install concurrently --save**

```
 concurrently "command1 arg" "command2 arg"
```

Kindly visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently if you want to use concurrently else https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all if you are fine in using **npm-run-all**

For running the commands in background create the app.js and use npm-command line library 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-command-line

```
    function runMultipleCommandWithoutWait() {
  Promise.coroutine(function *() {
    var commands = ["node --version","npm --version"];
    for(var i=0; i < commands.length; i++) {
      cmd.run(commands[i]);
    }
    console.log('Executed your command :)');
  })();
}
```

Comment: How can i let them to run  on the background?

Comment: provided you with the edit in the answer to run the commands in background @user10068878